# ANDROID: My MapView is only displaying grid lines. (I have checked around other boards fruitlessly)

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

When I load my MapView while debugging my application, the MapView only displays the greyis grid lines. I have tried:

1. Getting an API key with my debug signing certificate and including it in my MapView by using a .xml file that gets inflated
2. Checking to see that maps work in other applications (it does).
3. Cleaning the project and regenerating R.

EDIT:

1. Added uses INTERNET permission

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1 more thing in the check list, is the android.permission.INTERNET added in your manifest file?

Comment: ah yes, also enabled. Thank you though :0)

Comment: I guess posting the source would be helpful. Also, are you using the emulator? Sometimes the wifi connection does not get detected and thus the greyish grid

Comment: I have tried on both my phone and in the emulator. I am sure the phone has internet that gets detected, not very sure at all about the emulator. and what do you mean posting the source? I would be happy to post it, but to post all of the lines of source code would be a lot of room.

Comment: Try navigating to a particular site like www.yahoo.com if it loads, then you do have internet.

Comment: Internet works, MapView still doesn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: could you post your manifest?

Comment: Matt posting the lines of code where you are using the MapView would be helpful so that we could try to see where the problem exists

Comment: re-request your DEBUG key again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has started working randomly So I guess the problem is resolved. Thanks to everyone that tried to help. I will post back in here if it breaks again.

Comment: Did you ever understand how it got fixed? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try re-requesting your DEBUG key again.